# React: accessible unordered list of buttons

Tags: html, reactjs, accessibility, html-lists, arrow-keys

I'm creating an unordered list of buttons and would like to make it accessible. (**Note:** I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45449106/how-to-make-a-ul-list-of-buttons-accessible), but it doesn't answer my question.)

My code (simplified, in React) looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const items = [1,2,3,4,5];

const renderListItem = (_, index) => (
  <li key={index}>
    <button>Button {index}</button>
  </li>
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <main className="App">
      <button>Foo</button>
      <button>Bar</button>

      <ul tabIndex="0">
        {items.map(renderListItem)}
      </ul>

      <button>Baz</button>
    </main>
  );
}
```

I was able to make the `ul` tabbable by giving it a `tabIndex` of 0.

My problem is that this the user can still tab through each list item. In my real application the list consists of dozens of buttons and I feel like it would be a bad UX for people that rely on a11y having to tab through all of them. I've read that best practice would be to make the `ul` tabbable (as I did) and then allow them to enter the list using "space" and navigate the list using arrow keys, so that they can tab out at any point to the next element.

How could I something like this in React? I'm looking to learn how to:

1. Enter the list using "space".
2. Make the buttons "untabbable" and instead ...
3. Navigate the focus between the buttons using arrow keys.

Comment: I can't comment on the React way to do this but the principle is simple enough. Make all the items in the list `tabindex="-1"` and make the list `tabindex="0"` (as you already have). Then you need to make it so that when you press Space you take control of the focus when users navigate with the arrow keys. Because the container is a `<ul>` you may need to use `aria-labelledby` to provide a label / change markup. An alternative way that is much simpler is to supply a **visible skip link** above the section containing the buttons but it depends on your application as to whether you can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several cases of such long groups, you should probably provide other means to navigate as well. Headlines, for example, which would allow screen reader users to skip such groups or target a specific one.

Concerning tab navigation: I stumbled across a pattern called a *roving tabindex*, which is explained well on [MDN's Keyboard-navigable JavaScript widgets page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets)

The technical implementation is as following:

- Do NOT make the container focusable
- Make only the first item in the list (menu) focusable by giving all others to `tabindex="-1"`
- Add React logic to move (implicit) `tabindex="0"` attribute between items by means of arrow keys

There seems to be the [npm package react-roving-tabindex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-roving-tabindex) that already implements that logic, even with grid-navigation.

Otherwise a quick-fix might be to provide a hidden *skip link* just before the list of buttons that allows jumping over them. I'm assuming you are providing a title for your list?

```html
<hX>Title explaining the group</hX>
<p><a href="#skip-buttons">Skip group</a></p>
<ul>
<li><button>Button 1</button></li>
…
</ul>

<button id="skip-buttons">Baz</button>
```